# Correct way to add objects to an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-activity, performance, arraylist

I am trying to add an object to an arraylist but when I view the results of the array list, it keeps adding the same object over and over to the arraylist.  I was wondering what the correct way to implement this would be.

```
    public static ArrayList<Person> parsePeople(String responseData) {
    ArrayList<Person> People = new ArrayList<Person>();
    try {

        JSONArray jsonPeople = new JSONArray(responseData);
        if (!jsonPeople.isNull(0)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonPeople.length(); i++) {
                People.add(new Person(jsonPeople.getJSONObject(i)));
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return People;
}
```

I have double checked my JSONArray data and made sure they are not duplicates.  It seems to keep adding the first object over and over.

Comment: Everything looks right to me, as far as adding items into your list. Just out of curiosity, could you provide the code for your Contact class? Depending on that, and on how getJSONObject is implemented, I have some idea how it could be doing what you're describing.

Comment: Never ever catch the most abstract Exception silently. 

Never. And remove those "// TODO Auto-generated catch block" comments before posting or showing someone else, checking in the code. Disable the generation.

Comment: @user unknown: while you're right, I don't think it was worth down-voting the question over. It was pretty clear and useful, IMHO.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior:  Wasn't sure of the best way to post this since it is to large for a comment and not an answer.  The contact class can be found here: http://pastebin.com/3qSHCii1

Comment: Some users commonly append an "update" section to their original question, but pastebin works fine for me. Based on the code for the Contact class, I'm pretty sure the problem doesn't lie there. Since you've double-checked your input, I have to think that you're somehow checking the output incorrectly. Have you tried writing a unit test for this method? If so, what does it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is either a problem with the responseData string or the constructor.

If the class receives a response Data object that looks like the following

```
String responseData = 
"[{ 
\"first_name\" : \"fred\" , 
\"last_name\" : \"Nobody\"  
}, 
{ 
\"first_name\" : \"John\" , 
\"last_name\" : \"Somebody\"  
}]";
```

Then your Contact class should look like

```
public class Contact {
    String fname;
    String lname;

    public Contact(JSONObject obj){
        System.out.println(obj);
        try {
            fname = (String)obj.get("first_name");
            lname = (String)obj.get("last_name");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
//get and set methods
}
```

There should be no reason based on your logic to have the same record show up twice. Make sure your JSON string has the correct format coming in. I would suggest adding more System.out or Log4j calls in the application to determine every step. Worst case step through the application with a debug session.

PS - I built you app by adding the above code and it worked fine. So you have the grasp on adding the elements to the ArrayList properly. Could you also show how you print the array back out? Maybe the issue is there.

Comment: I would guess the fields are static in the OPs version of the `People` class.

Answer (score 3):

Some quick tips:

- Consider following [naming convention](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html#367). Variable names starts with lowercase.
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 65: Don't ignore exceptions*
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*

Having said that, you can `add` to an `ArrayList` the same way you `add` to *ANY* `List`: you can [`add(E)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) a single element or [`addAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) an entire [`Collection<? extends E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) to the end of the list. There are also overloads that takes an index if you want to add element(s) to a more specific location.

---

#### On aliasing

Always remember that objects are reference types, and references can be aliased. Unless you understand what this means, some behaviors may surprise you.

This snippet shows an example of:

- Creating a `List` of 3 `AtomicReference` instances that all refers to the same `AtomicInteger`.
- When the `AtomicInteger` is incremented, all `AtomicReference` sees this effect
- One `AtomicReference` is then set to refer to a second `AtomicInteger`

(There is nothing specific about concurrency in this example)

```
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
    //...

    List<AtomicReference<AtomicInteger>> refs =
        new ArrayList<AtomicReference<AtomicInteger>>();        
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        refs.add(new AtomicReference<AtomicInteger>(counter));
    }

    // we now have 3 AtomicReference,
    // but only 1 AtomicInteger

    System.out.println(refs);   // [0, 0, 0]
    counter.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println(refs);   // [1, 1, 1]

    refs.get(1).set(new AtomicInteger(9));
    System.out.println(refs);   // [1, 9, 1]

    // we still have only 3 AtomicReference,
    // but we've also created a second AtomicInteger

    counter.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println(refs);   // [2, 9, 2]
```

Note that even though a `new AtomicReference` was used for `List.add` every time (meaning 3 different `AtomicReference` objects are created total), they were still referring to the same `AtomicInteger`. This sorts of aliasing may be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you think

```
Person.add(new Person(jsonPeople.getJSONObject(i)));
```

should be like

```
People.add(new Person(jsonPeople.getJSONObject(i)));
```

i dono how you compiled the file in the first place, unless you have a static method called add(Person p)  and a constructor that accepts Person(JSONObject j) in the class Person.