# BankAccount program , adding to arraylist through a method

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I'm having a problem adding an object to an arraylist, using a method from class throws a error and I cant seem to find the problem. 
The error is `Error = non-static variable db cannot be referenced from a static contex`

Driver code (there are 5 cases but problem is in the case shown. last line above break)

```
package bankaccount;
import java.util.Random;
public class DriverClass 
{
    Database db = new Database();
    Database Deleted = new Database();
    boolean done = false;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while (!false)
        {
            int menu = IO.getInt("Please choose one of the following:"+
                    "\n 1 to create new account"+ "\n 2 to delete an account"+
                    "\n 3 to withdraw from an account"+"\n 4 to deposit to an account"+
                    "\n 5 to list all customers"+"\n 6 to list all deleted customers"+
                    "\n 7 to display single account "+"\n 8 to exit this program");

            switch(menu)
            {


            case 1:
                //Create bankaccount object  = creates new account
                String LastName = IO.getString("Please type last name: ");
                String FirstName = IO.getString("Please type first name: ");
                Name n = new Name (LastName,FirstName);

                //Create address object
                String street = IO.getString("Please type your address: ");
                String city = IO.getString("Please type your city: ");
                String state = IO.getString("Please type your state: ");
                String zipcode = IO.getString("Please type your zipcode: ");
                Address addr = new Address (street,city,state,zipcode);
                //Create Account number
                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(2000000000);
                AccountNum accno = new AccountNum(randomInt);
                //Create customer object
                Customer c = new Customer(n,addr,accno);
                //Create bankaccount object 
                double amt = IO.getDouble("Please type the opening account balance: ");
                BankAccount b = new BankAccount(c, amt);
                db.add(b);
                break;
```

& here is the code from the database class - calling the add method for array list
    package bankaccount;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Database 
{
    int index;
    boolean found;
    ArrayList<BankAccount> list;
    BankAccount acc;

    Database()
    {
        ArrayList<BankAccount> list = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    }

    public void add(BankAccount b)
    {
        list.add(b);
    }

    BankAccount remove (int i)
    {
        return list.remove(i);
    }

    BankAccount getaccount()
    {
        return acc;
    }

    ArrayList getlist()
    {
        return list;
    }

    int getindex()
    {
        return index;
    }

    boolean inlist()
    {
        return found;
    }

    void search (String key)
    {
        found = false;
        int i = 0;
        //int.length = list.size();

        while (i < list.size() && !found)
        {
            BankAccount b = list.get(i);
            if (key.equals(b.getcustomer()))
            {
                acc = b; found = true; index = i;
            }
            else 
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Error = non-static variable db cannot be referenced from a static context.   Appreciate any push in the right direction!

Comment: check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671610/add-object-to-array-list-get-error-when-try-add-obect-to-arraylist


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527137/correct-way-to-add-objects-to-an-arraylist

Comment: Thanks - ill check them out now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384908/add-object-to-arraylist-at-specified-index

Comment: Thank you for the links - did help me clarify how to add objects to arraylist.

Comment: On a side note - don't call your classes XxxxxClass (they are all classes). Don't call your variables 'c' or 'b' - this is meaningless to anyone reading your code (including you when you return to your code). Follow coding conventions (variables start with a lower case, i.e. 'deleted' not 'Deleted'. Name your classes for what they are BankApp would be better than DriverClass. This all gets easier with time, but starting out with good habits helps

Comment: Got it- thanks! I can tell experience is a major advantage over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the switch block you make reference to the `db` object which is not `static`, however you are in a static context (`public **static** void main`). The simple solution would be to change the line

```
Database db = new Database();
```

to

```
static Database db = new Database();
```

You will likely need to change the other two variables as well.